# algorithm2e: How to center the caption after removing its label and number?

Tags: algorithm2e

I managed to remove the caption label and number, but the new caption is not perfectly centered as shown below. So, how to literally center the new caption style?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}

\usepackage[
ruled,
vlined,
commentsnumbered,
shortend,
nofillcomment,
]{algorithm2e}

\SetVlineSkip{10pt}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{green!60!black}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
\SetKwComment{tcc}{\% }{ \%}

\newcommand{\mycapsty}[1]{\centering\normalfont#1}
\SetAlCapNameSty{mycapsty}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@algocf}{\AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt}}
\makeatother

\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{}
\setlength{\algomargin}{5mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \DontPrintSemicolon
        \BlankLine
        Algorithm Body\;\BlankLine

        \tcc{Loop}      
        \caption{long long long long long long  long long long long caption to center}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`algorithm2e` inserts some spacing which interferes with the centering. You can adapt by modifying your `\rightskip`:

Instead of

```
\newcommand{\mycapsty}[1]{\centering\normalfont#1}
```

write

```
\newcommand{\mycapsty}[1]{\centering\normalfont%
  \rightskip=\glueexpr\rightskip-2\AlCapHSkip\relax%
  #1}
```

[image]

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work in addition to unwanted vertical skip as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/BWiaG).

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Sorry, I adapted the answer. The problems should be fixed now.